# Comment form not working when separating views

Tags: django, django-views

I received some advice on separating my comment function into a separate view from 'ViewPost' view.

When I do this the comment section no longer displays comments, and form doesn't appear to add a new one.

Please see attached image for the code combined(I don't want to clog the question with code)

I am lost for ideas and hoping some one has some input to share.

**My views separated**

```
def ViewPost(request, slug):
    try:
        post = BlogPost.objects.get(slug=slug)
    except BlogPost.DoesNotExist: 
        print("Blog with this slug does not exist")
        post = None
    
    return render(request, 'mhpapp/view-post.html', {'post': post, 'slug': slug,})

def PostComment(request, slug):
    template_name = 'view-post.html'
    post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)

    comments = post.comments.filter(status=True)
    user_comment = None
    # Comment posted
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():

            # Create Comment object but don't save to database yet
            user_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            # Assign the current post to the comment
            user_comment.post = post
            # Assign comment to user
            user_comment.user = request.user
            # Save the comment to the database
            user_comment.save()
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()

    return render(request, template_name, {'post': post,
                                           'comments': comments,
                                           'user_comment': user_comment,
                                           'comment_form': comment_form})
```

**COMBINED WORKING CODE**

[image]

Comment: There's nothing obvious I can see wrong. Try putting a `print(comment_form.errors)` in an `else` after the `is_valid()` ..that's usually what's funky from my experience.
Also: **print statements, print statements everywhere** - make sure it's hitting the view, make sure comments has values, etc.

Comment: Can you also post your image code in the question so that somebody can just copy and Answer?

Comment: @SunderamDubey the code I have posted is the code that needs fixing.

Comment: @Nealium OK. The comments definitely has values because when I remove the view they all appear. I am using java script to to make the form appear once a button is clicked and even this does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're passing your `comments` separately in the context of rendering your template from the view.

Instead of rendering your comments separately, you can retrieve corresponding comments from the `post` object. Note here that it is a detailed view of the post, so we're retrieving just one post at a time with all its comments:

```
from django.contrib import messages

def get_post(request, slug):
    try:
        post = BlogPost.objects.get(slug=slug)
    except BlogPost.DoesNotExist:
        messages.error(request, 'This post does not exist.')
        post = None
    
    # You can pass a comment form here, which provides ability to post comments
    comment_form = CommentForm()
    
    # Notice here, `slug` is something you can get via `post` object
    # No need to pass it separately as another context variable.
    return render(request, 'mhpapp/view-post.html', {'post': post, 'comment_form': comment_form})
```

Notice the use of `django.contrib.messages` framework above. You can read [more about it here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/messages/#using-messages-in-views-and-templates)

In your HTML template, you'll do something like this:

```
{% for comment in post.comments.all %}
    {% if comment.status %}
        {{ comment.text }} - {{ comment.posted_by }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This would only have comments in your HTML page which have status of `True` similar to what you're doing in your `post_comment` view.

Next, you can have your `post_comment` view like this:

```
def post_comment(request, slug):
    template_name = 'view-post.html'
    post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():

            # Create a Comment object but don't save it to the database yet
            user_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            # Assign the current post to the comment
            user_comment.post = post
            # Assign comment to the user
            user_comment.user = request.user
            # Save the comment to the database
            user_comment.save()
        else:
            # You may include extra info here from `comment_form.errors`
            messages.error("Failed to post comment")


    return redirect('get-post', slug=slug)
```

Make sure to change the name of your view appropriately.

Comment: Thank you so much.... one question... why redirect to 'get-post' ? Should this not be same as view-post.html? Or must I create a new url

Comment: Also I couldn't find the 'snake convention' you mentioned before on pep8. Could you simply explain when and why using view names like the above is applicable? Many thanks

Comment: Hey David, you should use `snake_case` in function/variable names and `PascalCase` for class names. If you're having constants in your code, you depict them by all caps like this: `UNIVERSE_NUMBER = 42`.

Comment: We are redirecting to get-post, because that is the view that shows our blog post with all its comments. We are just separating the view to post comments. This is so that we have a `separation of concern` in our code. Also, @DavidHenson if this answer helps, you can mark it as accepted.

Comment: @DavidHenson you can look at Google's coding convention for Python code: https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#316-naming

Comment: The worked, but not in its entirety. It is not rendering current comments or comments that I post?

Comment: {% for comment in post.comments %} - 'RelatedManager' object is not iterable'

Comment: Ah, you'll have to do: `{% for comment in post.comments.all %}`

Comment: I added a variable  in my get_post view.  'comments = comments = post.comments.filter(status=True)' is this incorrect

Comment: You don't need this filtering and pass it as a separate context variable as I mentioned in the post. Are you using the filtering as done in the template snippet shown above, using the if clause for status?

Comment: I have tried your method again, and it is now working, I must have missed a character the first time. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252133/discussion-between-david-henson-and-sanyam-khurana).